# Any buildpack that can deploy Meteor with PhantomJS support on heroku?

Tags: heroku, seo, meteor

I'd like to run a Meteor.js app with the "spiderable" package on Heroku. Is there a buildpack or anything else to deploy it on Heroku? (PhantomJS in needed)

Comment: doesn't heroku's routing lead to problems because meteor needs sticky sessions?

Answer (score 1):

This buildpack (which I wrote) works with Meteor > 0.9.3 and includes phantomjs:

https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you're stuck with this, since in practice it's pretty straightforward to install an NPM module as [shown in this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/2fveyq). You only need to swap `underscore` in that example with `phantomjs`.

A very good buildpack to use is [oortcloud's meteorite buildpack](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite). I've used the [meteor-only](https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor) buildpack, but I've encountered way to many issues with it, but with the aforementioned I have had no problems with it so far.

As for the spiderable package, `meteor add spiderable`.

Fair warning though: running Meteor on Heroku requires alot of research on how to actually run your app, especially with providing correct environment variables. If you *will* have a problem with that, this would probably not a good place to discuss any of that.

On a side note: Next time, I implore you to be a little more clear about your problem and specify what your goals really are, and what have you tried so far. *Seriously, who upvotes these things?*

Comment: "Seriously, who upvotes these things?" People who are having the same problem.